# Consumer lag is decreasing abruptly on restart

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer running on worker instance.
Whenever the worker instance gets restart, the lag on consumer groups decline abruptly. Ideally when the worker instance gets up, consumer should start reading the messages from where it stopped rather than consuming all the messages with error.

I am sharing the graph showing consumer group lag.
I observed that on worker instance restart, the consumer lag is suddenly dropping causing all the consumer messages getting processed with some exception as below
LettuceConnectionFactory was destroyed and cannot be used anymore"
(Please note-> my consumer code is validating the messages based on the data present in redis-cache)
[image]